# how to call event from a Service in Ofbiz

Tags: ofbiz

How to call Event(Simple Method) for Ofbiz Service that written in Java.

is there a way?
I am using rest api to Create Employee in ofbiz, i created a wrapper for rest and from rest controller I am calling services of my own and from there calling ofbiz services, but Some creation processes had written in simple methods.

How can I call these events that written in simple methods from Service?

Comment: Do you want to call an event written in Simple method or a service written in simple method? Please give me an example of the simple method you want to call.

Comment: I want to call event written in simple method from a service written in java

Answer (score 0):

To call a simple method we should have two object

1. dispatach context object
2. map context

we can get dispatch contex object by

```
GenericDispatcher dispatcher = (GenericDispatcher)request.getAttribute("dispatcher");
DispatchContext dctx =  dispatcher.getDispatchContext();
```

In Java method/event, any service can be invoked by

```
GenericDispatcher dispatcher = (GenericDispatcher) request.getAttribute("dispatcher");
dispatcher.runSync("SERVICE_NAME", context);
```

context is map of required IN/IN-OUT parameters to service.This parameters cn be found in **webtool > Service Engine > click on SERVICE_NAME**

remember this

1. runSync —which runs a service synchronously and returns the result
   as a map.
2. runSyncIgnore —which runs a service synchronously and ignores the result.Nothing is passed back.
3. runAsync —which runs a service asynchronously. Again, nothing is passed back.

Comment: I want to call event from Service.

Answer (score 0):

Calling Simple Method from Java Service or Event

```
SimpleMethod.runSimpleEvent("Simple method file Location", "methodName", request, response);
```

To Get Request & Response Object From Service you have to pass those object as service parameter, like

```
<attribute name="request" mode="IN" type="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"/>
<attribute name="response" mode="IN" type="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse"/>

// Retrieving Request & Response object from context paramters 
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get("request");
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.get("response");

// For this you can refer payPalProcessor service definition...
```